# Prove $\int_{-1}^{0}f(|x|)dx =\int_{0}^{1}f(x)dx$

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals

This didn't really come out in today's test, but it had to hold true to agree with the numerical solution to a calculus problem in the test: Prove that

$$\int_{-1}^{0}f(|x|)dx =\int_{0}^{1}f(x)dx$$

I tried using the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus:

$$\int_{-1}^{0}f(|x|)dx = F(0) - F(|-1|) = F(0) - F(1) = -\int_{0}^{1}f(x)dx$$

which seem to disagree with the results. I suppose this is because $f(x)$ and $f(|x|)$ do not have the same integral. However, I am unsure of how to present a rigorous enough proof (let alone the approach of the proof).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Notice that if $x<0$ then $|x|=-x$ so just change the variable $t=-x$ to get the result.

Answer (score 0):

For $x \in [-1,0]$ you have $|x|=-x$, so:

$\int_{-1}^{0}f(|x|)dx=\int_{-1}^{0}f(-x)dx$

Now change variables by substitution $x=-t$$